# Mysql select last 2 elements ascending followed by 1st element

Tags: mysql

I want to select the last two elements in ascending order followed by the first element. Here is my code

```
   SELECT products.*, locations.logo FROM 
    (SELECT products.* FROM 
    (SELECT products.* FROM products AS products  ORDER BY products.id DESC )
    AS products LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=products.userid WHERE users.hide=0)
    AS products LEFT JOIN locations ON products.location=locations.id LIMIT 2
    UNION SELECT products.*, locations.logo FROM 
    (SELECT products.* FROM 
    (SELECT products.* FROM products AS products  ORDER BY products.id ASC ) 
    AS products LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=products.userid WHERE users.hide=0)
    AS products LEFT JOIN locations ON products.location=locations.id LIMIT 3
```

E.g. for 20 products now I'm getting

20, 19, 1 (ordered by id).

I'm trying to get 19, 20, 1.

At this moment the above statement works according to the E.g. I know I have to put an `ORDER BY`clause but I don't know where cause in my trials I'm getting error

```
"Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: i think you cant have order by clause on both select statements when you are doing union. Try to remove order by clause from first select query and try

Comment: Also order by clause should be last after you have completed making joins.

Comment: Oh dear. Where to begin? Well I'll start with LIMIT. Except in certain special circumstances LIMIT is meaningless without an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: how should I select the last two elements in an ascending order? To do that I have selected in descending order and limited to just 2. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: You have to start over. Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. We can take it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT id
  FROM
(
  (
    SELECT id, 0 sort_order
      FROM Table1
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 2
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT id, 1 sort_order
      FROM Table1
     ORDER BY id 
     LIMIT 1
  )
) q
 ORDER BY sort_order, id
```

Output:

```
| ID |
|----|
| 19 |
| 20 |
|  1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dca663/4)** demo

Comment: I adapted my code using your method, tested and it worked perfectly. Excellent answer, clear and easy to remember for the future. Thank you!